# Avoid blue outline on selected button + add style to selected button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a panel and I am running into some annoyances that I cannot figure out.

I have the min-height set up on

```
.panel_out {
    width: 23%;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #707070; 
}
```

So that the entire screen from my left margin to the 23% mark shows up in the panel_out color. However, only the `panel_buttons` are getting their color.

Then my active state, will not keep the color I have set when I select a `panel_button`. Then how do I get rid of the browser blue border when I click on the panel button?

Here is a fiddle to show what this looks like.

https://jsfiddle.net/ba98bjmf/1/

Comment: You've set no background colours apart from on the buttons?  Not actually sure what your question is

Comment: I want the background of the panel_out to be the same color as the buttons. I want this all to blend in together.

Comment: [add background-color to panel out then?](https://jsfiddle.net/ba98bjmf/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the blue border when selecting the button it's : `outline : none;`

If you want to remove the grey border on the button it's : `border : none;`

Is it what you were asking for ?

Comment: Yes, and then just how to keep my panel buttons background-color to stay active when selected.

Comment: Mmmh ok : do you want to keep their background-color in any case (will stay black), or do you want to switch between theses states (if you click again it will become grey again), or do you want that if you click another button the previous one will return grey ?

Comment: This...  want that if you click another button the previous one will return grey....

Comment: $('.panel_buttons').click(function(){    
     $('.panel_buttons').css("background-color","#666");
     $(this).css("background-color","#000");
})

Comment: (using jquery, it should do what you just asked  :)

Comment: I forgot to put it in the doc. ready tags. It works great, thanks!